# how selenium webdriver get data with class name?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, web-crawler

```
<li class='temp'> text1 </li>
<li class='temp'> text2 </li>
<li class='temp'> text3 </li>
```

In this code, I want collect all text which have 'temp' class.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('temp').text
```

but this code get only text1. how can I get all text with webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

If in the pages there are multiple elements with same criteria, `.find_element` refers to the first element.

You can collect as list with `.find_elements` and extract it using a loop:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('temp')
for element in elements:
    element.text
```

Or you can get all the text of `li` using the `ul` tag as the parent:

```
<ul class='...'>
    <li class='temp'> text1 </li>
    <li class='temp'> text2 </li>
    <li class='temp'> text3 </li>
</ul>
```

Use `.find_element` but please located the element refers to the `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe It works. Please try this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'temp')
```